# unable to pass confirm:$false to vmware powerCLI from groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, powercli

I have to stop the vm using PowerCLI in jenkins pipeline. getting below error while passing **-Confirm:$false** which is required to handle confirmation dialog

```
def stopVM(String vmName) {
        powershell (returnStdout: true, script: """ Stop-VM \"${vmName}\"  -Confirm:$false """)
    }
```

Error in Pipeline: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
[image]

Comment: as soon as you are using double-quoted string - you have to escape `$false` -> `\$false`, then groovy will not try to process it as a variable.

Comment: @daggett $ is mandatory so i can not escape.

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings

Comment: when you use `"... $false ..."` groovy is trying to substitute this placeholder with value of variable with name `false` before passing whole string to powershell. `"... \$false ..."` will be passed literally to powershell as `... $false ...`

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with same problem today. Escaping caused `$` sign to disappear so it is not a solution. Using tripple single quotes also since I have to pass param (as owner of question - vm name) so only possibility is to join different types of written string.
It should be something like:

```
 """Stop-VM "${vmName}" """ + '-Confirm:$false'
```

I'm not glad of that solution but it is working (and I didn't find any other solution)